# Limit a Source ticking frequency in Akka streams and always act on the latest message

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Here is a context of the problem:

1. There is a Source, it's constantly ticking, there is no guarantee about the ticking frequency
2. We want to limit the maximum ticking rate of the source (e.g., we are starting the messages in a DB, and we don't want to store more often than every 7 seconds)
3. We are only interested in the latest event, so if there is something new emitted during the 5-second wait time, we are only interested in that.

This is the best I could come up with:

```
Source.tick(5.seconds, 3.seconds, 1)
    .scan(0)((a, b) => a + b) // have a counter
    .wireTap(num => logger.warn(s"up   ${num.formatted("%02d")}"))
    .buffer(1, OverflowStrategy.dropHead)
    .throttle(1, 7.seconds)
    .wireTap(num => logger.warn(s"down     ${num.formatted("%02d")}"))
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)(materializer)
```

This almost works as I'd like it to work: there is a throttle that won't let more than one item every 7 seconds, there is a buffer before the throttle that will retain a single element, and replace it with a new one that arrives.

How ever, when I check the log, I can see that the behavior is suboptimal:

```
up   01
down     01
up   02
up   03
down     02
up   04
up   05
up   06
down     03
up   07
up   08
down     06
up   09
up   10
down     08
```

Instead of getting the latest element from the buffer the throttle uses the one that was in the buffer when the last throttled element was released. I.e. it looks like instead of pausing and then checking for a new element, throttle takes an element and waits with it untill a timer finishes.

Is there a better way to do this? Or should I implement my own flow?

Comment: Not sure but maybe [`conflate`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/conflate.html) could help.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own in a `GraphStage` where you have the exact control over when and how to push/pull elements.

Here's an example

```scala
  class LastElementWithin[A](duration: FiniteDuration) extends GraphStage[FlowShape[A, A]] {

    private val in = Inlet[A]("LastElementWithin.in")
    private val out = Outlet[A]("LastElementWithin.out")

    override val shape: FlowShape[A, A] = FlowShape(in, out)

    private sealed trait CallbackEvent

    private case object Pull extends CallbackEvent

    private case object Push extends CallbackEvent

    private case object Flush extends CallbackEvent

    private case object Finish extends CallbackEvent

    override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
      new TimerGraphStageLogic(shape) with StageLogging {

        setHandlers(
          in = in,
          out = out,
          handler = new AbstractInOutHandler {

            override def onPush(): Unit = asyncCallback.invoke(Push)

            override def onPull(): Unit = asyncCallback.invoke(Pull)

            override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = asyncCallback.invoke(Finish)
          }
        )

        private val FlushTimerKey = "Flush"

        protected override def onTimer(timerKey: Any): Unit = {
          if (timerKey == FlushTimerKey) {
            asyncCallback.invoke(Flush)
          }
        }

        private val asyncCallback = createAsyncCallback(new Procedure[CallbackEvent] {

          private var last: Option[A] = None

          override def apply(param: CallbackEvent): Unit = {
            param match {
              case Pull   => onPull()
              case Push   => onPush()
              case Finish => onFinish()
              case Flush  => flush()
            }
          }

          private def onPull(): Unit = {
            if (!isTimerActive(FlushTimerKey)) scheduleOnce(FlushTimerKey, duration)
            if (!hasBeenPulled(in)) pull(in)
          }

          private def onPush(): Unit = {
            last = Some(grab(in))
            pull(in)
          }

          private def onFinish(): Unit = {
            cancelTimer(FlushTimerKey)
            last.foreach(emit(out, _))
            completeStage()
          }

          private def flush(): Unit = {
            if (isAvailable(out)) {
              last.foreach(emit(out, _))
              scheduleOnce(FlushTimerKey, duration)
            }
          }
        })
      }
  }
```

Running it in a flow

```
    implicit val as: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
    val done = Source
      .tick(5.nanoseconds, 3.seconds, 1)
      .scan(0)((a, b) => a + b)
      .wireTap(num => println(s"up   ${"%02d".format(num)}"))
      .via(Flow.fromGraph(new LastElementWithin(7.seconds)))
      .wireTap(num => println(s"down ${"%02d".format(num)}"))
      .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.right)
      .run()
```

Produces

```
up   00
up   01
up   02
up   03
down 03
up   04
up   05
down 05
up   06
up   07
down 07
up   08
up   09
up   10
down 10
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the last element of n elements within a time window, you may use the `groupedWithin` operator and then `map`, sth like:

```
  Source
    .tick(5.seconds, 1.second, 1)
    .scan(0)((a, b) => a + b)
    .wireTap(num => println(s"up ${"%02d".format(num)}"))
    .groupedWithin(Int.MaxValue, 7.seconds)
    .map(_.last)
    .wireTap(num => println(s"down ${"%02d".format(num)}"))
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```